# Java result set issue - converting exception

Tags: java, sql-server, resultset

I have Database on my server which I am accessing via my Java app. First it was MySQL database but now we changed server and we are using SQL.

Now I am re-writing the code and I have exception when I am reading from it.

In one of functions I use the following select:

```
  String sql2="SELECT * FROM \""+item1+"\" WHERE name=? or codeID=?";
            pst2=con.prepareStatement(sql2);
            pst2.setString(1, listBox.getSelectedValue());
            pst2.setString(2, listBox.getSelectedValue());
            rs2=pst2.executeQuery();
```

When I try to get in while loop:

```
while(rs2.next()){
//some code
}
```

I am getting this error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '[some varchar value]' to data type int.

I understand what is the problem but I am not sure how to resolve it. I never faced this issue when I was working with MySQL.

Comment: ... You could try not reading texts as if they were numbers, but as if they were texts instead.

Comment: Well, you have in your loop a code like `rs.getInt(...)` on a nvarchar column. You need to read a `String` from it. Then you will parse the value in a numeric value.

Comment: is `codeID` a number? by any chance?

Comment: Yes, codeID is number.